# Automation trigger nifi Flow base on event

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I create a Flow extract data from MongoDB to Postgre.

**Problem**: There are so many documents in the source (100 mil). So I need to run FlowFile manually, insert 500k document each time and then select the last _id from dest for the next time.
My Flow:

```
GenerateFlowFile --> GetMongo --> ConvertJSONtoSQL --> ExecuteSQL.
```

I want to automate this task and I came with the idea is trigger Flow File with event driven (when queue is empty or using count variable) but I have found any solution yet.

Comment: Which queue and/or count do you mean? Also you should definitely use PutDatabaseRecord with a JSONTreeReader rather than ConvertJSONToSQL -> ExecuteSQL, PutDatabaseRecord does the same thing but as one transaction and more efficiently, plus I think ConvertJSONToSQL might be deprecated.

Comment: @mattyb Thanks for your recommendation, I'll definitely try PutDatabaseRecord. I also solve my problem by write a small program does migration job rather that nifi's Flow.